# How to modify the avro key/value schema in a RDD map transformation

Tags: dictionary, apache-spark, schema, rdd, avro

I'm trying to migrate some Hadoop Map Reduce code to Spark and I have doubts about how to manage map and reduce transformations when the schema of either the key or value change from input to output.

I have avro files with *Indicator* records that I want to process somehow. I already have this code that works:

```
val myAvroJob = new Job()            
myAvroJob.setInputFormatClass(classOf[AvroKeyInputFormat[Indicator]])    
myAvroJob.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[AvroKeyOutputFormat[Indicator]])       
myAvroJob.setOutputValueClass(classOf[NullWritable])

AvroJob.setInputValueSchema(myAvroJob, Schema.create(Schema.Type.NULL))
AvroJob.setInputKeySchema(myAvroJob,  Indicator.SCHEMA$)
AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(myAvroJob, Indicator.SCHEMA$)    

val indicatorsRdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(myAvroJob.getConfiguration,
  classOf[AvroKeyInputFormat[Indicator]],
  classOf[AvroKey[Indicator]],
  classOf[NullWritable]) 

val myRecordOnlyRdd = indicatorsRdd.map(x => (doSomethingWith(x._1), NullWritable.get)

val indicatorPairRDD = new PairRDDFunctions(myRecordOnlyRdd)
indicatorPairRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(myAvroJob.getConfiguration)
```

But this code works since the schema of the input and ouput keys does not change, is always *Indicator*. In hadoop Map Reduce you can define a map or reduce functions and modify the schema from input to output. In fact, I have map functions which process every *Indicator* record and generates a new record *SoporteCartera*. How can I do this in spark? It is possible from the same RDD or I have to define 2 different RDDs and pass from one to another somehow?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question... the problem was that you cannot change the RDD type, you must define a different RDD, so I solved it with the above code:

```
val myAvroJob = new Job()            
myAvroJob.setInputFormatClass(classOf[AvroKeyInputFormat[SoporteCartera]])    
myAvroJob.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[AvroKeyOutputFormat[Indicator]])       
myAvroJob.setOutputValueClass(classOf[NullWritable])

AvroJob.setInputValueSchema(myAvroJob, Schema.create(Schema.Type.NULL))
AvroJob.setInputKeySchema(myAvroJob,  SoporteCartera.SCHEMA$)
AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(myAvroJob, Indicator.SCHEMA$)

val soporteCarteraRdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(myAvroJob.getConfiguration,
  classOf[AvroKeyInputFormat[SoporteCartera]],
  classOf[AvroKey[SoporteCartera]],
  classOf[NullWritable])          

val indicatorsRdd = soporteCarteraRdd.map(x => (fromSoporteCarteraToIndicator(x._1), NullWritable.get))

val indicatorPairRDD = new PairRDDFunctions(indicatorsRdd)
indicatorPairRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(myAvroJob.getConfiguration)
```